# Hudson .jelly files edit not reflected

Tags: hudson, jelly

I edited a few .jelly files for Hudson, but it's not reflected. How do I restart Hudson ? I hope that this will display the HTML tag changes made in the .jelly files.

I am trying to change the look and feel of the Hudson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On what OS do you run Hudson? How did you install Hudson? .....

The basic idea is to stop Hudson (or just kill it) and than start it the same way it was started before. If you are not the person who installed it, call the person. After a while they get tired of you asking and will give you the instructions (and also the permissions) to do it yourself. ;)

Comment: We edited jelly files for a plugin here, restarted hudson, and failed to see a change. Is there other things we need to do (like rebuild the plugin code)?

Comment: What Do you mean by 'here'? If you mean `%HUDSON_HOME%\plugins\%PLUGIN_NAME%\...` I would check whether the change is still there after you restarted Hudson. If it is not, than you have to change it in the hpi file for the plugin.

Comment: Just had another Brain fart. Is the plugin, that you try to update a bundled plugin? In this case you have to pin the plugin, to ensure that the 'manually' installed plugin will be used. http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Pinned+Plugins

Answer (score 0):

If you have create plugin with **mvn -U org.jenkins-ci.tools:maven-hpi-plugin:create** command.
This will have in built Hudson.

You can run **mvn hpi:run** at location of plugin.
You can debug using **mvnDebug hpi:run.**

mvnDebug by default uses **8000** port,if you are using eclipse as IDE, Go to Run -> open Debug Config -> Select plugin and port and start debug. This will do remote debugging on 8000 port.